# PULL BIG VOLUMN DATA FROM ELASTIC SEARCH 6.8 ERROR

Tags: elasticsearch, out-of-memory, pull

I built ElasticSearch 6.8 cluster with default configuration in  3 nodes and stored about 30 millions data. Although i used "pagesize=1000", part of my ES cluster was crashed When i pulled about 10 millions of data . the log error info showed " out of memory " in some nodes. i studied documents of ES , but i don't found the solution.
Please help.

Comment: did try load balance for elasticsearch ?

Comment: 6.8 is EOL https://www.elastic.co/support/eol and no longer supported, you need yo upgrade